# A rather complicated join

Tags: mysql, join

It is not actually that complicated, I might have misled you with the title a little. Basically what I have is 2 tables

```
CREATE TABLE `friendships` (
 `sender` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
 `recipient` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

and `users` from which only the `id` column is involved in this problem.

`friendships` holds connections between people. What I am trying to do is get all friends of user `n` and information about them from the users table. The problem is that in `friendships` user `n` may be `recipient` OR `sender` so I need to get information on respectively the other person from the `friendships` record.

I don't even have the slightest clue on how I'm supposed to construct this join, is it even possible?

I guess it will go something like

```
SELECT * 
FROM friendships LEFT JOIN users ON ???=users.id WHERE recipient=n OR sender=n
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT * 
FROM friendships f
LEFT JOIN users s ON s.id = f.sender 
LEFT JOIN users r ON r.id = f.recipient 
WHERE n in (f.recipient, f.sender)
```

Comment: Oh my god.. Seriously.. How have I not thought of that *facepalm*. Thank you!

Comment: This actually doesn't solve my problem, it selects both sender and recipient information. I only need the one that is not with id `n` :(